# Magento extension not working in my design

Tags: magento

I have just installed a new extension for my Magento webshop.
It's a count down function that shows when to order if the order is to be shipped the same day

When using the standard design, the extensions works:
[image]

When I switch to my own design rwd/default - the counter disappears:
[image]

I have installed other extensions and the all works perfectly with my design.
How do I fix this?

Comment: I think you need to copy layout and template files of your new extension to your rwd/default theme.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: So Enigmativity.....you know the answer and knows it's not programming-related. Nothing in the code needs to be changed? Just a little copy / paste and everything is fine? Thanks for the non-related-help ;-)